# second time with this problem with my error page from no results found javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, search

So I have a problem as I have been trying to create a no results found redirect in my javascript but just can't seem to get it to work, any help would be appreciated and please don't add a completely different code to what I have published just add to it and tell me where to put it, thanks

```js
function openPage() {
        var x = document.getElementById("search").value;
             x = x.replace(/\b\w/g, (firstLetter) => firstLetter.toUpperCase());

//=======================================================================================

            if (x === "Aaron Carter") { 
                 window.open("files/aaroncarter.html");
            }

            if (x === "Albert Einstein") {
                window.open ("files/alberteinstein.html");
            }

            if (x === "Alex Higgins") {
                window.open ("files/alexhiggins.html");
            }
            }
```

```html
 <form action="" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" onchange="openPage()"  class="form-control rounded-pill rounded-end-0 border-0 ps-4" placeholder="Search... e.g. Stan Laurel">
                  <button type="button" id="button" onclick="openPage()" value="Chercher" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill rounded-start-0 shadow-none">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use eventListener and the submit event.

Note I changed the button to a submit by removing type=button

```js
const files = {
  "johndoe": "files/johndoe.html",
  "janedoe": "files/janedoe.html"
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let x = document.getElementById("search").value;
    x = x.replace(/\s+/g,"").toLowerCase();
    const file = files[x] || "files/notfound.html";
    console.log("Opening",file)
    // window.open(file)
  })
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" />
<form id="searchForm">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control rounded-pill rounded-end-0 border-0 ps-4" placeholder="Search... e.g. Stan Laurel">
    <button  id="button" value="Chercher" class="btn btn-primary rounded-pill rounded-start-0 shadow-none">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hey do I add that javascript at the bottom of my current js code?? also what is the https link you have added?? I wont use someone else's links

Comment: also this doesnt work I tried it

Comment: What do you mean by someone else's link? I added font awsome so the magnifying glass works. If you type John Doe, your window will open johndoe.html ditto Jane Doe will open janedoe.html and anything else will open notfound.html - if that is not what you want, then you need to elaborate on your needs. This is what I understood from your description

Comment: And you can add the script anywhere. The DOMContenLoaded is when the page has finished loading the HTML so you can put my script anywhere. I normally put it in the head. You can add more things to search for: `const files = {  "johndoe": "files/johndoe.html", "janedoe": "files/janedoe.html", "someotherstring" : "files/elsewhere.html" }`

Comment: hey! yes I have added code for you to add the code I need and explain where to put it

Comment: You have added what code to where?

Comment: the code above you inputted and nothing works with that

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. If you run the snippet it works - I can only guess if it works like you want. But it does something. If that something is wrong, perhaps you explain better what you want and why my script does not do that?

Comment: please scroll to top and see code I originally added and you have completely changed this and it doesnt work so if you can't just add the code I need to my existing snippet thats fine ill ask another question

Comment: I rewrote your script to something that should work better with your request. In my script you can still enter `John Doe` and you will be redirected to `files/johndoe.html` or enter `Jane Doe` and be redirected to `files/janedoe.html`. Anything else redirects to `files/notfound.html` - if you want this to work some other way, then tell me. 
You took the input and made sure it was capitalised and then had to test each name, I take the input, remove spaces and lowercase it and if found in the object I made, I go there